# I do not want all the "addToBasket" buttons to change when i click on a specefic "addToBasket" button. Only the clicked button should change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, chakra-ui, array.prototype.map

[image]

On clicking an "add to basket" button that specific button should get replaced by `-` and `+` buttons.
Right now all of the mapped buttons are getting changed at the same time.

How to inflict change only on one "add to basket" button?

Using: React, Chakra UI buttons, and the `.map` function.

```js
 {products.map((item) =>  {
            return (
             <Box key={item.id} border="1px solid black" h="auto" >
              
              <Link  to={`/product/single-product/${item.id}`}>
                
                <Box h="auto" border="1px solid black">
                <Box><Image src={item.image} h="fit-content" /></Box>
                <Text h="fit-content" >{item.name}</Text>
                <Text h="fit-content" >Rs.{item.price}</Text>
                </Box>

              </Link>

                <Box  align="center" border="1px solid black" h="50px" > 

                { addToBasket && <Button  onClick={() => handleAddToBasket(item)} ml="5px" >ADD TO BASKET</Button> }
                { addBtn && <Button ml="5px" onClick={handleReduceItem} >-</Button> }               
                { addBtn && <Button ml="5px" >+</Button> }

               </Box>
               
              </Box>
            
           )})}
```

button onClick functions are here:

```js
const [addToBasket, setAddToBasket] = useState(true);
const [addBtn,setAddBtn] = useState(false);

 function handleAddToBasket(singleProduct){
   
    if(addToBasket === true){
      setAddToBasket(false)
      setAddBtn(true);
    }
    dispatch(addToCart(singleProduct))
  
  }

  function handleReduceItem(){
    if(addBtn === true){
      setAddToBasket(true)
      setAddBtn(false);
    }
  }
```

[image: before clicking all button visible]

[image: after clicking all button are replaced by plus minus buttons]

Comment: You're using _one_ state for `addBtn` and using that for _all_ buttons. So you need to figure out a way to distinguish what item you want those conditions triggered for. Perhaps by checking the basket for that item and using that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution only for add To Basket  button.
Note: You can utilize your Redux store state. I'm using local state only.

First, You are using addToBasket state for all products and it's boolean value. So whenever you change the state of addToBasket is effects in all products.

Change this Boolean to an array.

```
const [basket, setAddToBasket] = useState([]);
```

In handleAddToBasket make this changes.

```
const [basket, setAddToBasket] = useState([]);
const [addBtn,setAddBtn] = useState(false);

function handleAddToBasket(singleProduct){

  if(!basket.includes(singleProduct.id)){
    setAddToBasket((ids) => [...ids, singleProduct.id])
    setAddBtn(true);
    dispatch(addToCart(singleProduct))
  } else {
    const newBasket = basket.filter((id) => id !== singleProduct.id)
    setAddToBasket(newBasket)
    // call your remove from cart dispatch here or however you want to handle it
  }
}
```

In jsx

```
<Button  onClick={() => handleAddToBasket(item)} ml="5px" >{basket.includes(item.id) ? 'ADDED' : 'ADD TO BASKET' }</Button>
```

I think instead of just hiding the button you should display a text `ADDED` for already then you can toggle the item in your cart.